# A word/phrase for what one says about her internal feelings such as love?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there any word/phrase for that kind of utterances by which people talk about their internal feelings rather than external objects?

Compare for example: 
1) there was an accident in that street. 
2) I love you.

The first utterance is about an external object, but the second one consist in talking about

Comment: @Try to form a sentence and leave the blank in place of ghost word.

Comment: Your own term *feelings* works for that example.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the first answer to some extent, as you wouldn't confess or profess that there was an accident. But "confess," as the answer says, implies revealing something, which might not always be the case with feelings: you might not hide them at all. "Profess" sounds solemn. I would add that "express" fits some situations where "confess" and "profess" don't fit, for example, you might express joy but probably not confess or profess it, and you wouldn't express that there was an accident. For a citation I will note a helpful website: the One Look Dictionary Search at https://www.onelook.com/.

Answer (score 1):

For love, we might "confess". "He confessed his love for her." We'd use this for some internal feeling that we've been holding inside, and carries the weight of letting it out.

We might also "profess" our love. "Profess" basically means "to claim", but is usually used for our own feelings and beliefs, which can't be directly seen by others. It is often used ironically, however, and so may imply the opposite (that they claim to have a feeling/belief but really don't).